# Recursively renaming extension of all files with a given extension

Tags: windows, filenames

I need a way to remove an extension from all files that have have .failed extension added. The folder structure has sub trees e.g.:

c:\Folders\Level1\Level2\fileName1.xml.failed
c:\Folders\Level1\Level2\fileName2.xml

Would result in the folder Level2 containing:
fileName1.xml and fileName2.xml.

There are hundreds of sub folders that have the .failed extension.

Any ideas?

Comment: What language are you using? Or are you using a shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code if you using shell

```
for /R %x in (*.failed) do ren "%x" *.
```

Comment: A different but related question. It did what I needed on a local file path. In production I need to run it against a file server I have access to e.g.:
\\fileserver.domain.com\docs\submit\files\
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.

Any ideas how I could run it against that location as I will be unable to run the command against that location from the command line.